# Display view block in custom field

Tags: views, 6

View block need to display in custom field and need to pass nid as a argument for that view block. Help me on this.

Comment: What you meant by `custom field` ?

Comment: @NikhilM Custom field -> CCK text field other than node body

Comment: Idea is to use `nodeapi` hook and in the view mode make the desired CCK field to hold the rendered HTML of view by passing the arg

Comment: @Nikhil Is there any way to do same functionality with out any code changes. expecting to be done through any community modules or from admin side.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: we can use [insert_view](http://drupal.org/project/insert_view) module to add view in CCK field.